# Как получить id чата в telegram?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def upper(message: Message):
    r = requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/getUpdates').json()
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text.upper())

    print(r)
```

Ответ

```
{"ok":true,"result":[]}
```

Почему резалт пустой?

Answer (score 0):

Могу ошибаться, но было что то вроде этого,
используя только библиотеку requests

```
import requests
URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot132123/'
response = requests.get(URL + 'getUpdates').json()
for i in response['result']:
    print(i['message']['chat']['id'])
```

Comment: это же тоже самое?